# VSTS to TFS on-premises data migration

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I would like to migrate all possible data from my VSTS Project to an on-premises TFS server 2015.

I don't know which data can or cannot be migrated, the most important for me is the history of versions and the source control code.

I've watched the internet about it but found only tutorials from 2014...

I'm aware of tools like OpsHub but I want a free solution if it's possible.

If someone can help, it will be appreciated

Thanks all (and forgive my bad English, not my native language).

Comment: What's the result after trying with opshub tool?

Answer (score 0):

The only option is via third-party tools. There is no capability to migrate from VSTS to on-prem TFS.

For version control migration, it's fairly easy to migrate TFVC repos via *git-tfs* -- you have the TFVC repo converted into a Git repo, then convert the Git repo back into a TFVC repo in the target system.

If you're already using Git, it's as simple as adding a new remote to your repo and pushing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Witch third-party tool did you recommend ?

Comment: @G33KO Try it with [opshub tool](http://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/)